# ESO: how to identity what style of armour you have?

Tags: ps4, the-elder-scrolls-online

[image: my armour set so far, just cant't figure out what style they are]The story started a few days ago. I had most of my armour broken and I kept dying. Also I didnt have sholders, hands , shoes and leggings.

Then I got the thives guild dlc and thought to myself, "what if I steal my armour set from merchents." So I did. But I can't find the leggings to compete the set.

What I want to do now is craft them myself (for expirence) but I want to craft the correct style so it doesn't look ugly.

The armour is: heavy iron armour.
My charchter:Im in the Ebonhartpact im an imperial and im level 11.
I got the armour in "Davon's Watch'.

I also have the money and resources to make it and I lnow how blacksmithing works.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Why the downvotes

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the armor, it's impossible to tell you the correct style.

However, considering you've stolen it in the Ebonheart Pact, it's most likely the style of one of the Ebon Heart races.

What you can do is start creating a new character with one of the Ebonheart races and try to find those wearing similar armor in the preview (or look online for images).

You can also steal leggins that are on display in shops or around crafting tables. There are leggins, it might just be a bit tricky to find them.

As an alternative, considering you've got money and resources, just buy the other racial styles of the Ebonheart Pact (shouldn't cost you more than around 500-1000g for all three, if you need them; **don't** buy them off the crown store, look at Guild Vendors instead) and craft one piece of each. You don't have to craft the highest level to save on metal. All iron armor of a given style will look exactly the same, so just craft some level 1 leggins and deconstruct them once you've found the right ones.

Comment: Here is the updated question